# How to compare with the string when the same string received in different order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

**How to compare with the string when the same string received in  different order?**

Eg: in  my table there is two columns named as `"meaning","Relevant name"`
column data type is in `varchar`

**meaning   -  Relevant name**

```
food -  snacks;choco;chips
```

**input** -  `" choco;chips;snacks "`

**output** -   `"food"`

how this type string will be compared?Could anyone suggest any idea

Comment: create another table `RelevantType` which will contains foreign key against food and use joins with it

Comment: If possible you should change the design such that snacks,choco,chips are each on their own row in a one-to-many type table, this makes queries like this trivial.  As it stands your difficulties in dealing with multiple values in a single row are going to get much worse in the future, it is simply not how relational databases are designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Putting CSV data in a column is bad; relational databases aren't designed to be treated that way. Have multiple rows for your values:

```
Meaning|RelName
food   |snacks
food   |choco
food   |chips
```

And split your input when querying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Meaning FROM t WHERE RelName IN ('choco','chips','snacks')
```

The split and query formation should be done in your frontend language

Do not use string concatenation to build your SQL with values, i.e. this naive way (c# syntax):

```
//this is bad - forming a list of values by replacing ; with',' and concatting
//into  anotehr sql string
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Meaning FROM t WHERE RelName IN ('" + input.Replace(";", "','") + "')";
```

Do use parameters together with string concatenation:

```
//this is good 
//declare the base sql stub
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Meaning FROM t WHERE RelName IN (";
//split the input into values
var foods = input.Split(';');

//for each value
for(int i = 0; i < foods.Length; i++){

  //add a bit to the sql with a new parameter named
  sqlCommand.CommandText += "@param" + i + ",";

  //add a parameter name and value to match the just-added parameter
  sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("param" + i, foods[i]);
}
//the sql ends with a comma; a syntax error. trim it and put a ) to close the IN
sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlCommand.CommandText.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
```